# Swagger - How to add definitions on child objects in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-codegen

In C# (Asp.Net Core) )I have the following documentation over a child object of type **NameValue**.

I wish to have the documentation I added here over **FromWarehouse**, but when Swagger renders, it uses the definition for **NameValue**, not **FromWarehouse**.

```
/// <summary>
///     The warehouse this transfer is coming from
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>GLW, WDI, PSO, SMA, SHW</remarks>
public NameValue FromWarehouse { get; set; }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 3 things:

1. The summary should be moved from class property to class.

not here

```
public NameValue FromWarehouse { get; set; }
```

but to

```
/// <summary>
///     The warehouse this transfer is coming from
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>GLW, WDI, PSO, SMA, SHW</remarks>
public class NameValue{
....
```

2. You need to add document generation, with Include Xml Comments

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));
});
```

3. Add this to your .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This is the example I used

```
/// <summary>
///     The warehouse this transfer is coming from
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>GLW, WDI, PSO, SMA, SHW</remarks>
public class NameValue
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     The Name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    ///     The Value
    /// </summary>
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

The remarks, I was not able to include the, but as far as I understand, remarks are used to provide payload example, and it is used on top of the resource method.

All this I use with dotnet 6 and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore Version 6.2.3.

I hope it helps.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) to Microsoft documentation.

Comment: That's too bad. NameValue is a common type used in hundreds of places so subclassing it would be not feasible.

Comment: I got you, will try to give one more shot and see if I can bring more.